# Is there a way to allow mouse drag navigation

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

Does jsxgraph support a drag navigation system, where the bounding box would shift along with the cursor when dragged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it suffices to enable the `pan` attribute:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox',{
            axis:true,
            boundingbox: [-10,10,10,-10],
            pan: {
                enabled: true,
                needShift: false
            }
        });
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/vcL7aepo/1/ . Further information can be found at https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/JXG.Board.html#pan .

Best wishes,
Alfred